# Ubuntu 19.10 Can't find .local folder

Tags: files, directory

I'm new to Ubuntu and I can't find `.local`. I looked everywhere and tried using the search function. Apparently that's where the applications install so I really need access to it.

Comment: No, that's not where most applications install to. That's one possible location for your manually-installed software. But apt, snap, flatpak, AppImage, Pip and other common installers DON'T install to .local.

Comment: Tell me, what is the real problem that you're trying to solve?. Finding the .local folder probably won't solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to enter to `.local` folder using the next command:

```
$ cd ~/.local
```

If you got:

```
bash: cd: ~/.local: No such file or directory
```

then it have not been created because of software using it have not been installed or run, or have been removed by someone.

It does not exist by default.

Default content of `~/` user's folder is:

```
$ ls -ailh /etc/skel/
total 48K
1835117 drwxr-xr-x   3 root root 4.0K Mar  2 01:45 .
1835009 drwxr-xr-x 164 root root  12K Mar 21 23:21 ..
1837168 -rw-r--r--   1 root root  220 May  5  2019 .bash_logout
1837169 -rw-r--r--   1 root root 3.7K May  5  2019 .bashrc
1845947 drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4.0K Mar  1 22:56 .config
1845949 -rw-r--r--   1 root root  15K Sep 29 17:56 .face
1837170 -rw-r--r--   1 root root  807 May  5  2019 .profile
```